# Angular Syntax: How to use ng-repeat $index in expression

Tags: angularjs

I have following code:

```
<form name="reviewForm_{{$index}}" ng-controller="reviewController as reviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewCtrl.addReview(product)" novalidate>
            <blockquote class="newReview">
                <b>Stars {{reviewCtrl.review.stars}}</b>
                <p>{{reviewCtrl.review.comment}}</p>
                <cite>{{reviewCtrl.review.author}}</cite>
            </blockquote>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.stars">
                <option value="1">1 star</option>
                <option value="1">2 stars</option>
                <option value="1">3 stars</option>
                <option value="1">4 stars</option>
                <option value="1">5 stars</option>
            </select><br />
            <textarea ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.comment" required></textarea>
            <label>by:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.author" required /><br />

            <div>reviewForm is {{reviewForm_$index.$valid}}</div>

            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

The Form above lies within a ng-repeat and has the name **reviewForm_$index**.
That works fine. So it will give reviewForm_0, reviewForm_1 and so on.

Now I would like to check if the form is valid with **{{reviewForm_$index_$valid}}**.
For some reason it doesn't show anything. 
Do I have the wrong syntax?

Comment: Fairly certain the `reviewform_$index_$value` should be `reviewform_$index.$valid` but I can't check right now.

Comment: You have to use quotes since reviewForm is just a string and $index is an actual model in your scope.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, the second underscore should be a dot. But that's what i've tried. Doesnt work.

Comment: What do you expect it to be (with or without the dot)?

Comment: Can you show your controller? Would make the question a bit more clear.

Comment: The first underscore seems to be the problem as well, you don't have anything like `reviewform_$index` in your scope, right? And that won't be a reference to your form element, you have to select it somehow.

Comment: As far as I know you  can address the form via its name. When I look inside my scope I find reviewForm_0 for example. There is nothing much in my controller. I tried the same thing with a single form with a hardcoded form name attribute and it worked like expected

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to access a property that does not exists since  `reviewform_$index` will be treated as a form name not a variable. So change your code to something like this:

```
<div>reviewForm is {{reviewCtrl['reviewForm_' + $index].$valid}}</div>
```

That will work!!

Comment: Can you please provide a plunkr or so?

Comment: Hope this works, bit messy. Click on one of the links called Reviews. http://plnkr.co/edit/vX0LnjndPyTG1m39r3gf

Comment: @Kiwi Juicer because ng-repeat creates a new scope, each form name will be on a different scope, so you could in principle use the same name. See demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/RRf1KuGPCb7ptZbyNi93?p=preview But I would try to avoid the form nested in ng-repeat as it looks like overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to work thanks to @klode.
Here my solution:

```
        <form name="reviewForm" ng-controller="reviewController as reviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewCtrl.addReview(product)" novalidate>
            <blockquote class="newReview">
                <b>Stars {{reviewCtrl.review.stars}}</b>
                <p>{{reviewCtrl.review.comment}}</p>
                <cite>{{reviewCtrl.review.author}}</cite>
            </blockquote>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.stars">
                <option value="1">1 star</option>
                <option value="2">2 stars</option>
                <option value="3">3 stars</option>
                <option value="4">4 stars</option>
                <option value="5">5 stars</option>
            </select><br />
            <textarea ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.comment" required></textarea>
            <label>by:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.author" required /><br />

            <div>reviewForm is {{reviewForm.$valid}}</div>

            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

As explained by Klode can I leave the form name without the **$index** trailer and address the form's **$valid** property each loop via it's name just so: reviewForm.$valid